# what is the extname for the file .vimrc

Tags: javascript

A question stumbled me around the word extname! Attention please! I'm not ask for a solution, the major point is the word `extname`.

In the home page of the https://scriptoj.com/, I found a question which demands completing a function called extname, through which input is a filename and output is the extname.

```
const extname = (filename) => {
  /* TODO */
}
```

when I submitted the code bellow,

```
const extname = (filename) => {
  /* TODO */
  var dotIndex = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
  var extname = "";
  if(dotIndex != -1){
    extname = filename.substr(dotIndex);
  }
  return extname;
}
```

the error catcher warned me that

> if the input is `'.hello'`, the `''` should come out but not the `'.hello'`

[image]

Comment: [Do dotfiles have a file extension?](/q/32173890/6567275)

Answer (score 0):

> if the input is '.hello', the '' should come out but not the '.hello'

Then simply check if `dotIndex` is not `0` and do not `substr` the name if this is the case.